# Delete any "pair" of adjacent letters with the same value in a string

Tags: c++, string, optimization, micro-optimization

For Example-

**aa**ab**ccdd**d  -> abd

**aa**a**cc**c**bbcc**cd  -> a**cc**d-> ad

**abba** -> Empty sting

I first tried the approach below. The splitString function is called until the string cannot be reduced further(i.e. length of the string we provided (a) = length of the string obtained after performing operations.
This code give **Memory Limit Exceeded (MLE)** error for values around 10^5, however **runs fine for values less than 10^5.**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void splitString(string str)
{
    int a=str.length();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==str[i+1]){str[i]=1; str[i+1]=1;}
    }

    string alpha="";
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            alpha.push_back(str[i]);
    }

    int b=alpha.length();
    if(a==b)
    {cout <<b<<"\n"<<alpha; return;}
    else
    {splitString(alpha);}

}

int main()
{
    int n; string str; cin>>n>>str;

    splitString(str);

    return 0;
}
```

The second approach I dropped rcursion:
However this gives **Time Limit Exceeded (TLE)** error for values around 10^5 but **works fine for small values.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 100005

void foo(char *s){
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i, j;
    j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] != '$')
        {
        s[j] = s[i]; j++;
        }
    }
    s[j] = '\0';
}
char* super_reduced_string(char* s){
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < len; i++){
        if(s[i] == s[i-1])
        {
            s[i] = s[i-1] = '$';
            foo(s);
            len = strlen(s);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);
    char s[size]={0};
    scanf("%s", s);
    char* result = super_reduced_string(s);

        printf("%d", strlen(result));
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I **optimize** these solutions?

[Input1](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/coderun-round1/problems/d0a1a57a3f-in03.txt?Signature=021awoBWYGliuFpiLEc18z1wQmg%3D&Expires=1578848237&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA6I2ISGOYH7WWS3G5) [Input2](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/coderun-round1/problems/d0c183ea3f-in04.txt?Signature=LUW6Cl1m0muCza57zuKRED3aZt4%3D&Expires=1578848237&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA6I2ISGOYH7WWS3G5) [Input3](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/coderun-round1/problems/d1205f003f-in05.txt?Signature=anb9J9uLdEy2yqmy2GBnfQ2Y7iw%3D&Expires=1578848237&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA6I2ISGOYH7WWS3G5)

Comment: You can run in-place instead of copying to a new `string`, just a read pointer and write pointer that start out pointing to the same character, but the write pointer doesn't move for runs of the same character.  Or for odd-length runs of the same character, move it forward by 1 to leave the 1 non-paired value.

Comment: Do you have any sample input files or input-generating functions that we could benchmark with if we wanted?  Are long runs of the same letter common?  How *micro* are you looking to get with your optimizations?  Like manual vectorization with x86(?) SIMD to apply the same brute force faster, if long runs of a single letter are common?

Comment: Oh, your 2nd version *is* already in-place, but restarting a pass every time it finds a pair!!!  And redoing strlen every time.

Comment: If I do not restart and place a $ sign each time I find a pair, and then call function foo. It gives readjusts the string without the $ signs. But this doesn't solve our problem. For aaacccbbcccd , i will get accd. Thats why I restart. I am stuck, *sigh*

Comment: @PeterCordes I added Inputs. I also tried s[i] != '\0'; instead of i < strlen(s), TLE still persists.

Comment: Yes, you need to do *something*, but your options include looping to the end of the string, *then* starting a new pass.  (Like your recursive version but using a loop instead of tail recursion).   You might even be able to just backtrack by 1 character after eliminating an even-length run; I'm not sure if that would avoid needing multiple passer over the whole thing, or if it would just (usually) reduce the number of full passes.

Comment: Your sample input links are broken.  Is this from https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/super-reduced-strings-303701dd/?

Comment: Anyway, on that site you can just look at already submitted answers, like https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/35083740/.  The couple I looked at aren't great coding style, but at least that one I linked is readably formatted.

Answer (score 3):

There are several improvements you could make to your current algorithm, like directly removing characters without storing a `'$'` as filler.  e.g. do one in-place pair-removal pass (like your 2nd version but not stopping after the first pair), then repeat until the length stops changing.  (In a loop instead of tail recursion).

But really a different algorithm makes a lot more sense.

**This is possible in-place (O(1) storage), in a single pass (O(n) time) with low constant factors**, probably on the order of a couple to a few clock cycles per byte when compiled for modern x86.  Branch misprediction is probably the biggest variable.

This looks like it's from an existing online problem. 
 https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/super-reduced-strings-303701dd/.  You can look at existing solutions like https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/35083740/ (and see that many are coded like crap, with global variables and 1-letter var names, and `i < strlen(s)` that re-runs `strlen` every iteration.)  But the actual algorithm from the 2 I looked at was good (other than the strlen in the loop making it O(n^2), and confirmed my idea that it would be possible to do it in one pass if you're able to keep backtracking after collapsing a run of pairs creates a new pair between the odd letters from before and after the gap.  i.e. you can go back and look again at letters that were going to be part of the output.

My version is kind of optimized for inputs that might have runs of 3 or more of the same character, not just scattered pairs, but it's fine in that case, too.

To micro-optimize away a check for back-tracking off the beginning of the string, the actual string data is in a buffer that has a leading `0` byte (`'\0'` character).  This means we don't need to check `wpos != 0` before `buf[wpos-1] == c`.

**The hacking contest / exercise web site lists this under "stack" exercises.  You can think of the write position as a stack.**

```cpp
// This is my version.  Don't submit it as yours on online contests.
// But feel free to use it in anything else.  Licence = public domain for the code part of this answer.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// first non-match = one past the end of a run
inline size_t find_not(const char *base, size_t pos, char needle) {
    while(base[pos] == needle) {
        pos++;
    }
    return pos;
}

static char static_buf[10000002];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *buf = static_buf+1;
  int infd = 0;
  if (argc>1) infd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

  //size_t len = 
  read(infd, buf, sizeof(static_buf) - 4);  // FIXME: short read isn't handled
  // 1 byte of padding at start with a value that can't appear in strings simplifies backtracking
  // I don't think we read past the end; c !=0 so checking for runs of that can't go too far.

  //static_buf[0] = 0;  // str[-1]
  //str[len] = 0;

  size_t rpos=0;
  while (buf[rpos] && buf[rpos] != buf[rpos+1])       // std::adjacent_find
        rpos++;
  // read-only until first pair, or end of string.  could SIMD this with a byte-shift like palignr to feed pcmpeqb
  if (buf[rpos]) {
      // we stopped early, on a pair
    size_t wpos = rpos;    // next write position.  prev char = a 0 before the string, or last non-pair
        rpos+=2;             // read from after the pair
//  rpos = find_not(buf, rpos+2, buf[rpos]);               // read from after the run
//  wpos += (rpos-(wpos+1)) % 2;                           // odd run length -> keep one, else 0

    char c;
    while ( (c = buf[rpos]) != 0) {
        size_t run_end = find_not(buf, rpos+1, c);
        if ((run_end - rpos) % 2) {
            // one char left from the read side, cancelling or not with the write side.
            if (buf[wpos-1] == c)                  // the 0 before the start of the string always compares false
                --wpos;
            else
                buf[wpos++] = c;
        }
        rpos = run_end;
    }
    buf[wpos] = 0;
  } // else we hit a terminating 0 without finding a pair

  puts(buf[0] ? buf : "Empty String");

  if (infd == 0)
      lseek(infd, 0, SEEK_SET);   // rewind stdin so another run under perf stat can re-read
}
```

Assuming that one `read` will read all the available input is not a good idea.  It might not, e.g. from a pipe.  I used POSIX `read` instead of stdio `fread` because I thought I was going to use the length instead of calling `strlen`.  C stdio line-input functions are mostly dumb and don't return the length they just found for the line.

Another micro-optimization for GCC would be to write `(run_end - rpos) % 2` as `(run_end + rpos) % 2`.  GCC knows that unsigned `%2` just takes the low bit, but it doesn't realize that when you only want the low bit, ADD, SUB, and XOR (add-without-carry) are all equivalent, differing only in the high bits where carry/borrow/nothing propagate from the low bits.  `+` is commutative and can be implemented on x86 with an LEA instruction to copy-and-add.  In this particular case it happens to save 2 `mov` instructions around a `sub`, instead just doing an `add`/`and`.

([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaXABylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmIgATM9IAHVNMJLamnfpGHl4%2BdBZWtroOTq4ycpgKvgwEzMQE/noGnMay8op0yakE4Tb2ji5u0ilpGYHZMtXFlqVR5a4AlDKo2sTIHADkAKTOAMyWyDpYANSDI%2BpV%2BKgAdAiz2IMADACCw2O0E9rTs%2BratHgLK2ubO6Pjk5gzc9IAntIA9ATP7pjSlyPr212d0OD2OL3eVWYBD%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%2B7%2BsNRZVTMzgAGzDEtrEzXac3SN1oVhhuLZbQeLVUtaq5nYx2ILCAIA4XwJmqAQYi4momHnauh3JsmcFtVhOHEnQrDPFMpyKKwkr4hKDJ4tqJABWoyVVJpohLKuaDaKwF4MHZACyNJuTpInMpyrHsZgxLSO6VCoXgpn0mweDALQppEDi5oXu4yB6ZgACOdiYXgd77bNgZVdagz2o6ToNS6DxVB%2B3wXthxCAzDBZclDxCS4NEouoal6HfVZ1MVYAAeOuaRxhbePktAowaOazmupphlyEUOPF0n%2BYjWkw6awgEkStDEhrr1vR9Do1V2htvTHTHeReVDEKguiclTjgpf5IfbFicZbZez3SrK01UNq4duOt5WbSLJ1BTHdcXb9CdJynzBp8z/mJZibxxrrXiLRHNIQFtxIQL322Js%2BYvOL6UxR3a9cL4vTEYBeiVTGhwBE8SaxTLTmDuLSVjanIshXmWcY1o%2B31ZhN7BTBA99VntG2HaLIVhTVV5ixLWZxtr3KnDEGyMMBcZSoDlERbkCZWzGnopLOMAt75D0AWyGiW0p4z2cN/PqTo4xxmXlYJ269MBUxxM3DOXlsIXm8FgY0Ig%2BisAFHxWGsphKiQocJC2ss8BYEKr/WMzpEHFxbGPZq3UQxhmQKdResdsTMgeG7EhJBPay0aMleRGktKclYC6ZgrxqzJwZDmHS%2BVWA%2Bn4bggRTpiTEjHkePBViT6YHgVYuMQs7R2M%2Bg6Bakj7GuNLBYvOYZEpAJetfNMuCAkRPcXYnxn8xr9VtDSJiTjPJTHdEpFKjhdCWChFoiKhMEDdAlAXLR6tmB4iKgabQBBpDCIquIkYAAxCuUwQCLWcNgPSnwpjJCRsAYYWC/HHimEI181IwwbCXFmVcZjzSmTwgRK82oGDYGwAAaTEKsgAKvRI22IcwiXhgsdS0gooiHASyBKpxgZqHTt8YgHIKxyQLDmYk8cSyZi2P0TorAQD9F9P0UgBh%2BgbCBagf56hIo9D6ItEYnAgUEH%2BWC9onRTIgG4E6JYhhfRLW4BsQwzpuCYu4JwEYvohD/O4ECkFYLSAQv6EC6QIANikCRaCn5pA4CwBgIgFAhjJpkAoPKAV7AnDIGAE6NwuJWAcXxJQOwyKgV2FycQZ4/yEWkDQLoXQD1AK0EBkq0gWAySiHYEa/AOZEizh%2BEazAJsEg1IGJqvscgjUCjsJZNVmgsAasRZpXQfrOg0HoEwNgHAeD8EEMIUQIAJBiCkB65lkBOgfhtsy/oxJAIjCmMSAA6mwMGxIqDuDwJgJl8REjKAgKYWoWQTBqBKJEaIghDShD8FoTIraQg2ybWUJwnA4h5CSI0OtghcgJBtoUNIfbWgDoaEUMdg7BJNAiP2rgnQzkwojb8/5gLgVGoZSbQwS1iR4qysgKsWLnD31wIQWGuxB1TE0HpQVcLnzPsRUq1FpB0W%2Bg2EsHg5KnScCdBsX0/7fQnopX8/o1LSCBsMCMJYBKNjcBtEtQwnBfQ8BxTaA9HL6X/KZSytl36uW8ogEgYp7gankEoNq0tYrBAWnvfOkNjAWDmsjS6Sy7gg2UoBTSw9/zH1sKJse0956xxXqWM4L9HKf0shwuUCAu64NAsDZwJaSwQNOl9KMbI3AcU8GngRulDKSOsvZSitFIB/2Ae4MB0D4HIPQcEyMYThHLNkcU%2Bp%2BTCGuDtnM%2BC4jvnbOkBtfiXwGKgA%3D%3D%3D))

The asm output is a rats nest of branching, unsurprisingly. :/  If large runs were *expected*, it would be possible to use x86 SIMD to scan 16 bytes at a time for a run of the same character.  Like `_mm_set1_epi8(c)` and `_mm_cmpeq_epi8` / `_mm_movemask_epi8` to get a bitmask of comparing against the next 16 bytes.  Keep going if it's all-ones, otherwise `__builtin_ctz(~match_bitmask)` to find the first mismatch.  `run_end +=` that.

I tested this with input files downloaded from the contest, concatenated repeatedly to make one big file (using `yes $(<input.txt) | tr -d '\n' | head -c 3000000 > big.txt`).  The input.txt I tested with is this one:

> kzgnywawwacatvccwcpehkgbizefkstszqobqjephaderkwqviqcmdjuxxqutskmxlljsxccicmcddauhwngklfvbqfonkbktqvogolczxmkehycgrmhygfwjvnxtomcygecnkwqzljqshzlarrxfgyamcpemtsqympmmiyngtioifpemaainhueolkndcguoclnobfidksxyzyvnamtrkhwsjkrqxfakfpmyonjanckthlkpyguyhhtscocumxxbycvkxrtlskzuorgpzeohpxfxgeunjfcfccyibcbynnpdjopbcjuodsjdzocezdymzfjrzezyfnkelrliakfabrungdynzjebuwcrdrtzmdlunaibohg

My version agrees with one of the working contest submissions, although I didn't test every possible corner case (like a pair or run of 3 at the start and/or end).

It's more than twice as fast as the [purported "best" submission on the contest](https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/29848385/), which is still O(n) but not in-place, and written less efficiently (e.g. storing `'\0'` into the array on "pop", as well as with terrible formatting and bad coding style (global variables).  And this is *after* I look `strlen` out of the loop for Thor8's submission.  That made unusably slow, like I killed it after 10 seconds vs. finishing in ~12 milliseconds for that 3MB input.

IDK how the online judge compiles and times anything, but even the original version with strlen in the loop (which doesn't get hoisted at compile time for some reason) didn't take anywhere *near* 0.1 seconds for the tiny 372 byte input it tested with.  Yet the online judge claims times like 0.101484 sec.  Unless perf testing happens with some much larger input you can't download?  IDK how nobody submitted anything that was faster than having strlen in the loop, unless the online judge perf testing is just broken.

My version is less than half the instructions and cycles, and just under half the branches vs. Thor8's, when compiled with gcc9.2 -O3 and profiled on my i7-6700k (Skylake) in `perf stat` for that big input).   Branch mispredict rate is low (0.58% on my SKL i7-6700k) because the input repeats the same pattern every 372 bytes

**This is not great benchmarking.  I'm profiling the whole process including dynamic linking startup overhead, and it only runs for ~10ms, and I didn't bother to control for I/O methods between versions**.  I did repeat the whole *process* 100 times to give `perf stat` something to average over, and to get the CPU up to max turbo for most of the runs.  If I cared more about accurate results instead of ballpark estimates, I'd run it in a repeat loop.  The algorithm runs in-place but re-copying a *small* buffer between iterations would be fine.

```
# mine
$ perf stat -r 100 ./pjc-strpair.gcc-O3 < big.txt >&-

 Performance counter stats for './pjc-strpair.gcc-O3' (100 runs):

              5.37 msec task-clock                #    0.970 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.12% )
                 0      context-switches          #    0.047 K/sec                    ( +- 17.41% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               561      page-faults               #    0.104 M/sec                    ( +-  0.03% )
        20,892,724      cycles                    #    3.893 GHz                      ( +-  0.07% )
        47,546,026      instructions              #    2.28  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.01% )
        12,299,984      branches                  # 2291.692 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
            70,862      branch-misses             #    0.58% of all branches          ( +-  0.23% )

        0.00553091 +- 0.00000647 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  0.12% )
```

After a `-fprofile-generate` + training run, rebuilding with `-fprofile-use` makes it run in 3.61 ms.  9.6M branches, 0.17% mispredict rate.  14M cycles, 44.6M instructions (so fewer total instructions).  Using `-fno-pie -no-pie` as well takes it down to 41.7M instructions but saves less than 1% cycles.  (Interestingly cuts the branch miss rate in half, but it was already low enough not to hurt performance on this easy data).

GCC doesn't unroll loops at all unless you use `-fprofile-use`, and it probably helps GCC lay out branches better, with common cases as fall-through.

```
# thor8, "best" submission
$ perf stat -r 100 ./thor-strpair.gcc-O3 < big.txt >&-

 Performance counter stats for './thor-strpair.gcc-O3' (100 runs):

             12.19 msec task-clock                #    0.985 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.24% )
                 0      context-switches          #    0.011 K/sec                    ( +- 26.00% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
             1,120      page-faults               #    0.092 M/sec                    ( +-  2.19% )
        47,525,048      cycles                    #    3.898 GHz                      ( +-  0.24% )
       125,445,423      instructions              #    2.64  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.08% )
        28,943,829      branches                  # 2374.152 M/sec                    ( +-  0.07% )
           110,100      branch-misses             #    0.38% of all branches          ( +-  0.14% )

         0.0123707 +- 0.0000296 seconds time elapsed  ( +-  0.24% )
```

Notice twice the number of page faults from touching twice as much RAM.

`-fprofile-generate` / `use` only speeds it up to 11.21ms, but like my version branch misses dropped a lot.  **According to `perf record` / `report`, 41% of its time is spent inside `__vfscanf_internal`, so much of the difference *is* in I/O overhead, not the algorithm.**  vs. 23% in `main` itself (much of the rest in the kernel for page faults.  When even a less-efficient version of the algorithm is faster than `scanf`, that's a pretty good sign that it's efficient enough.  But you asked about micro-optimizations as well as optimizations.

I had to add a `rewind(stdin)` to Thor8's version (and lseek to my version), otherwise the later runs under `perf stat -r100` will see an empty stdin!

More instructions per cycle in this case just means it did the same real work with more instructions.  And the better branch prediction *rate* is because it was doing more total branches, some of them totally predictable like the `top!=-1` part of one loop condition.

GCC does inline the function calls and optimize the global vars into registers for Thor8's version, but there's still some sign-extension from 32-bit signed `int` to 64-bit pointer width since I compiled for x86-64.

I assume *most* of the run time is coming from the actual loop, although stdio `scanf` has to look for a word boundary vs. `read` is just a memcpy (inside the kernel).  Still, real programs do have to do I/O, and my version is optimized based on the fact that we have to read input from stdin anyway, not an input buffer, so it doesn't cost anything extra to have a leading `0` in the array and read it in after that.

---

**Implementing this in idiomatic C++ is left as an exercise for the reader**.  There is no `find_not` in C++ so you could use my version, or use `std::find_if_not` or `std::find_if` with a lambda as the predicate.

There is [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) which can implement the read-only loop that stops at the first duplicate.

Avoiding copying when reading into a `std::string` or `vector<char>` with a prepended `0` byte might be a challenge.  Implicit-length strings seems to be helpful for this challenge because finding a match for a known-non-NUL `c` also tells you the char you just looked at is non-NUL.  So you don't also need to check lengths.  Of course it's just a minor constant factor to add an extra check to a loop, still O(n) runtime.

Comment: Never expected such an optimized soln for this problem.

Comment: @Abhineet: It kind of caught my interest thinking about the problem after I commented.  (Plus, I have close to enough answers in the optimization tag for that gold badge, gamification doing its job encouraging me to actually post the results. :P)

Comment: I saw this problem first time as [Neutralisation of charges](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/charges-repel/) under the "array" exercises. Most of the people solved this using stack when it was clearly stated that it was to be done through array. {The same problem is renamed as "super reduced string" in the stack section}. This was the first question I ever asked here. Thanks a lot @PeterCordes , I learned many new things.

Comment: @user10325089: Stack and array aren't mutually exclusive.  C doesn't have a "stack" built-in so you typically implement one on top of an array, exactly like I'm doing here.  `wpos` is the top-of-stack.  I didn't write functions called push and pop, but `wpos--` is a pop+discard and `buf[++wpos] = c` is a push.  Instead of always pushing into the stack and then popping matching pairs, I optimized that away, though.